# How can I make a linear regression plot also output the uncertainty of the regression itself given uncertainty in the data?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I was wondering if it possible to have TikZ/`pgfplots` output a linear regression which also gives me the uncertainty of the regression itself. Sort of like this:

[image: graph]

note how a and b have an uncertainty.

Currently, I have this

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
     \pgfplotsset{width=11cm,
         compat=1.3,
         legend style={font=\footnotesize}}
     \begin{axis}[
     title={$R_1$:Experimental Plot I vs. V},
     xlabel={V},
     ylabel={I}},
     legend cell align=left,
     legend pos=north west]

     \addplot+[blue][mark size=1.5pt] table[row sep=\\,
     y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] % compute a linear regression from the
     %input table 
     {
           X Y\\
           0.44 0.001   \\ 
           -0.44    -0.001  \\ 
           4.24 0.008   \\ 
           -4.40    -0.008  \\ 
           9.68 0.018   \\ 
           -9.99    -0.018  \\ 
           15.56    0.029   \\ 
           -15.64   -0.029  \\ 
           18.67    0.035   \\ 
           -18.67   -0.035  \\
     };
     \addlegendentry{%
         $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot a
         \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$ lin. Regression} %

              \addplot+[blue,only marks,mark=*,mark size=1pt][error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,
        x dir=both,x explicit] 
      coordinates {

        (   0.44    ,   0.001   ) +- (  0.01    ,   0.00025 )
        (   -0.44   ,   -0.001  ) +- (  0.01    ,   -0.00025    )
        (4.24,0.008) +- (0.01,0.002)
        (-4.40,-0.008) +- (0.01,-0.002)
        (9.68,0.018) +- (0.01,0.0045)
        (-9.99,-0.018) +- (0.01,-0.0045)
        (15.56,0.029) +- (0.01,0.00725)
        (-15.64,-0.029) +- (0.01,-0.00725)
        (18.67,0.035) +- (0.01,0.00875)
        (-18.67,-0.035) +- (0.01,-0.00875)
      };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks in advance.

edit: I'm not asking for the r^2 value for the regression, I'm asking for the uncertainty of the regression itself.

Comment: Please edit your question to make your code fragment into a compilable example, starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also, please explain how you calculate the result you're looking for. I don't mean: how you do it in TeX/PGF code. Obviously, that's what you want help with. But how would you do it manually? If you don't know how to do it manually, you need to find that out first as it is not, obviously, a question for this site.